# Read binary file bit by bit

Tags: perl, binary

Is there a way that I can read a binary file bit by bit, without saving it as an array?

I have a very large binary file that I need to to read it bit by bit. And saving it as an array takes a lot of time, so I want to prevent this. I don't care what happened to the file content.

```
$size = stat($args{file});
my $vector;
open BIN, "<$args{file}";
read(BIN, $vector, $size->[7], 0);
close BIN;

# The code below is the part that takes a lot of time.
my @unpacked = split //, (unpack "B*", $vector);
return @unpacked;
```

Comment: You can read a file byte by byte... that should be a sufficiently small granularity.  But reading it one megabyte at a time should work just fine also, and be much more efficient.  You need to explain why you need to read one bit at a time.  _"Saving it as an array"_ does not take a lot of time.  Reading the entire file into memory might exhaust memory, but reading a file in really small chunks will be much slower than using larger buffers.

Comment: the file conains 1 Billion bits! it's 125MB. I don't have a problem of memory, I have a problem of runtime.. saving the file into array of '0' and '1' take about 80 minutes! and this is not good for me.

Comment: If reading 125MB takes 80 minutes you are doing something wrong. This should take a second or two. Post your code.

Comment: see the post, I just added the code..

Comment: You haven't yet explained what you want to do with `@unpacked` and why you need an array of bits.

Comment: I want to do X if the bit is 1, Y if its 0.. the unpacked is just translating the binary file into list of 0,1 to know what to do (X or Y). Can I use $vector in any way ? if yes how ?

Comment: Read the file in by one byte increments, using bit shift operations to retrieve the nth bit from each byte.

Answer (score 1):

Read in the file 1 byte at a time using the special `$/` variable, and then use bitwise operators to check each bit in the byte. Should end up being something like the following:

```
$/ = \1; # read 1 byte at a time
while(<>) {
    my $ord = ord($_);

    # for each bit in the byte
    for(1 .. 8) {
        if($ord & 1) {
            # do 1 stuff
        }
        else {
            # do 0 stuff
        }

        # move onto the next bit
        $ord >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin [`vec`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#vec) function to manipulate Perl scalars as bit vectors.